# I want to include space in my value when setting Enviroment variable

Tags: powershell, shell, command-line, environment-variables

in the terminal

[image]

```
set TOKEN=Bearer allthebest
```

when I use `Get-Variable` to confirm my input,

I get `TOKEN=Bearer` as the variable name and `allthebest` as the value.

I expect
`TOKEN` as the name and `Bearer allthebest` as the value.

Comment: As an aside, I would set the token to allthebest and use an f-string to prepend Bearer unless there was some compelling reason to not do that.

Comment: In short: While trying to use `cmd.exe` syntax `set FOO=BAR` to define an environment variable happens to work _syntactically_ in PowerShell, it does something very different. The real PowerShell equivalent is `$env:FOO = 'BAR'`. See the linked duplicate for details.

Comment: I've done it for this post, but please [format your posts properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) in the future.